# How do I get the top 5 value from groupby and value_counts?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a [dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15_klD4NWgVNmji-UUAYZWivDvxcG58qjV1Q5h3oV52k/edit?usp=sharing) (let's call it df) that looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is to find how the normalized value (via value_counts(normalize = True)*100) of the top 3 nationality per source_type

So, it should look like:

[image]

So far I have tried this:

```
df.groupby(['Source_Type'])['Source_Nationality'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100
```

But the above code is giving the WHOLE dataset (see below)

[image]

So I tried adding .head(3). This one only shows the top 3 of the citizen and not the news part.

```
(df.groupby(['Source_Type'])['Source_Nationality'].value_counts(normalize = True)*100).head(3)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried .nlargest as well, but it didn't give me the result I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your case try `head`

```
out = df.groupby(['Source_Type'])['Source_Nationality'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100
out = out.sort_values(ascending=False).groupby(level=0).head(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `head` to each of the groups. Try:

```
>>> df.groupby("Source_Type")["Source_Nationality"].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).head(3))
```